# inner-join doctrine data fetch

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to fetch some data from doctrine ---

Example --- from (**MyBundle:MyEntityOne**) --- by $**id** need to find **name**, where name is connected to another entiry named "**MyEntityTwo**".

than from  (**MyBundle:MyEntityTwo**) --- I need to find the **$item** based on the **name** we got from "**MyEntityOne**".

Can anyone have an idea how to write the query for it.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of relationship is between EntityOne and EntityTwo?
First define the relationship between them in EntityOne and EntityTwo

on OneToMany like this: One EntityOne have Many EntityTwo use this query in your EntityRepository on EntityOne:

```
 public function findAllItems()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $query = $qb->select("o","t")
                ->from($this->getEntityName(), 'o')
                ->innerJoin("o.name","t")
                ;
        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();

    }
```